# Problem with multirow and multicolumn in LaTeX

Tags: latex, multirow

I have a problem with the creation of a table on LaTex while using multicolumn and multirow.
Here the code that I'm using

```
\documentclass[12 pt, letterpaper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{multirow} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[super]{nth} 

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%http://latexcolor.com/
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0} %giallo ocra

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!b]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc|ccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Periods and Hours} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{amber}Total} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{amber}First period} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\cellcolor{amber}Second Period} \\[0.5ex]
      & \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}\cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper& \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper& \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper\\[0.5ex]
    \hline
     \multirow{2}{3em} TIR (\%) PP1 & 54,02 & 14,59 & 31,38 &48,7 &9,48&41,77&59,9&20,29&19,8\\
      Hour(h) & 57 & 15 & 33 &27 &5&23&30&10 &10\\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output

[image]

I don't know why the TIR and Hours is so mess up. Please help me :(

Comment: Don't bother with `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`. Have a look at the `tabularray` package instead. It makes merging cells soooooooooo much easier

Comment: ... that being said, please make a compilable [mre] instead of just a code fragment

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, you are missing the `{...}` around the final argument

Comment: i've added the final rows of the table..

Comment: This code won't compile. No documenctclass, not the necessary packages, no`document` environment....

Comment: Hope it is clear now!

Comment: Did you actually test the code from your question to make sure it compiles?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yep, same problem as the one in the picture

Comment: Definitely not. It will error much earlier with `\usepackage before \documentclass. ` as error message.

Comment: In my latex file they are in the correct order, I wrote it here wrongly.. despite this and the use of \tabularray, do you know what can cause my problem?

Comment: Please do write it here correctly. Also add the other missing bits like how your `S` and `s`  columns are defined so we can compile your example and the work on a solution.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz modified with all your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `\multirow{2}{3em} TIR (\%) PP1` is wrong. `\multirow` has 3 mandatory arguments, the last one the content of the cell. So if you actually want to merge two cells, you need `\multirow{2}{3em}{ TIR (\%) PP1}` (notice the `{...}` around the cell content)

... that being said, the cell below this is already filled with `Hour(h)`. If you want the cell above to be merged with this one, you have to leave it empty.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, letterpaper, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{multirow} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[super]{nth} 

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%http://latexcolor.com/
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0} %giallo ocra

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!b]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc|ccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Periods and Hours} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{amber}Total} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{amber}First period} &
      \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\cellcolor{amber}Second Period} \\[0.5ex]
      & \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}\cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper& \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper& \cellcolor{amber}hypo & \cellcolor{amber}normo & \cellcolor{amber}hyper\\[0.5ex]
    \hline
%     \multirow{2}{3em}
     TIR (\%) PP1 & 54,02 & 14,59 & 31,38 &48,7 &9,48&41,77&59,9&20,29&19,8\\
      Hour(h) & 57 & 15 & 33 &27 &5&23&30&10 &10\\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Personally, I would use the `tabularray` package, this makes merging cells so much easier:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0} %giallo ocra
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={l|ccc|ccc|ccc},
    cell{1-2}{2-10} = {amber}
  }
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Periods and Hours &
    \SetCell[c=3]{} Total & & & 
    \SetCell[c=3]{} First period & & &
    \SetCell[c=3]{} Second Period & &\\
    & hypo & normo & hyper& hypo & normo & hyper& hypo & normo & hyper\\
    \hline
     TIR (\%) PP1 & 54,02 & 14,59 & 31,38 &48,7 &9,48&41,77&59,9&20,29&19,8\\
      Hour(h) & 57 & 15 & 33 &27 &5&23&30&10 &10\\
      \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```